# Fails to create azure container right after storage account was created

Tags: bash, azure, terraform, azure-rm

I am trying create an storage account from terraform, and use some of its access keys to create a blob container.
My terraform configuration is given from a bash file, so, one of the most important steps here are the following:

```
customer_prefix=4pd
customer_environment=dev

RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=$customer_prefix
az group create --name $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --location westeurope

# Creating Storage account
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=4pdterraformstates
az storage account create --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME  --sku Standard_LRS --encryption-services blob

# We are getting the storage account key to access to it when we need to store the terraform .tf production state file
ACCOUNT_KEY=$(az storage account keys list --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --query [0].value -o tsv)


# Creating a blob container
CONTAINER_NAME=4pd-tfstate
az storage container create --name $CONTAINER_NAME --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --account-key $ACCOUNT_KEY

source ../terraform_apply_template.sh
```

I am sending those `az cli` commands from a `.bash` file and so, I am sending other `TF_VAR_azurerm ...` variables there

Finally when I execute the bash first bash file, this call to the `terraform_apply_template.sh` which create the plan, and it's applied. Is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Terminates script execution after first failed (returned non-zero exit code) command and treat unset variables as errors.
set -ue

terraform init -backend-config=$statefile -backend-config=$storage_access_key -backend-config=$storage_account_name

#TF:
function tf_plan {
    terraform plan -out=$outfile
}

case "${1-}" in
    apply)
        tf_plan && terraform apply $outfile
        ;;

    apply-saved)
        if [ ! -f $outfile ]; then tf_plan; fi
        terraform apply $outfile
        ;;

    *)
        tf_plan

        echo ""
        echo "Not applying changes. Call one of the following to apply changes:"
        echo " - '$0 apply': prepares and applies new plan"
        echo " - '$0 apply-saved': applies saved plan ($outfile)"
        ;;
esac
```

But my output is the following, the `azurerm` backend is initialized,the storage account named `4pdterraformstates` is created, and also the `4pd-tfstate` blob container,

[image]

but in the practice this action is not effective, I get the following output:

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: storage: service returned error: StatusCode=404, ErrorCode=ContainerNotFound, ErrorMessage=The specified container does not exist.
RequestId:2db5df4e-f01e-014c-369d-272246000000
Time:2019-06-20T19:21:01.6931098Z, RequestInitiated=Thu, 20 Jun 2019 19:21:01 GMT, RequestId=2db5df4e-f01e-014c-369d-272246000000, API Version=2016-05-31, QueryParameterName=, QueryParameterValue=
```

Looking for a similar behavior, [I have found this issue in the azurerm provider terraform repository](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/841)

And also according to [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7005) created directly in terraform repository It's looks like a network operational error ...
But the strange is that it's was fixed ..

I am using the terraform v0.12.1 version

```
⟩ terraform version
Terraform v0.12.2
```

According to @Gaurav-Mantri answer, is necessary wait until the storage account to be provisioned in order to continue wit the other task related with the storage account itself.

> Creation of a storage account is an asynchronous process. When you execute az storage account create to create a storage account, request is sent to Azure and you get an accepted response back (if everything went well).
>
> The whole process to create (provision) a storage account takes some time (maximum 1 minute in my experience) and until the storage account is provisioned, no operations are allowed on that storage account.

How can I include a wait process after of the storage account creation?
It seem that only with the bash `sleep` command or pausing the bash shell with the `read` command for some time is not enough..

Answer (score 2):

Creation of a storage account is an asynchronous process. When you execute `az storage account create` to create a storage account, request is sent to Azure and you get an `accepted` response back (if everything went well).

The whole process to create (provision) a storage account takes some time (maximum 1 minute in my experience) and until the storage account is provisioned, no operations are allowed on that storage account.

This is the reason you're getting the error because you're immediately trying to perform an operation after sending the creation request.

Not sure how you would do it but what you would need to do is wait for the storage account to be provisioned. You can get the properties of the storage account periodically (say once every 5 seconds) and check for it's provisioning state. Once the provisioning state is successful, you can try to create a container. At that time your request should succeed.

Comment: Great explanation. How can I include a wait process after of the storage account creation? It seem that only with the bash `sleep` command or pausing the bash shell with the `read` command for some time is not enough.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven’t worked with bash to help you out further.